# No Member named stoi in namespace std

Tags: c++, string, parsing, compiler-errors, string-parsing

I am testing out `std::stoi` function found in the link below:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol
but I got the error:

> No Member named stoi in namespace std.

What should I do?
Please advise thanks.

P.S: I am using Xcode Ide to do my c++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()  {
   std::string test = "45";
   int myint = std::stoi(test);
   std::cout << myint << '\n';
}
```

Image

[image: no member named stoi in namespace 'std']

[image: error]

Comment: Did you compile with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: I doubt so. and I'm not sure how and where to check whether I compiled with -std=c++11.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you need a compiler that supports C++11 and you need to compile in "C++11 mode" (in some cases).

Secondly, if this is in fact an *intellisense* issue (and it looks like it may be), then it could simply be that your IDE doesn't support C++11 yet.

Comment: I have C++14 support and I have the same issue. It's clearly related to CLang or its components. Nothing to do with the language version setting though.

Comment: @PabloAriel You probably missed something. While there are gaps in support for C++17 in Xcode (e.g. no `std::optional`) even in C++17 mode, C++14 is old enough now and I am not aware that support for something as core as `std::stoi` is missing.

Comment: The problem comes because of this:

`#if ((__cplusplus >= 201103L) && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99)  && !defined(_GLIBCXX_HAVE_BROKEN_VSWPRINTF))`

However, nobody mentioned a solution other than defining _GLIBCXX_USE_C99 and nobody provided an explanation on why should I add such definition manually (looks like a bug to me though).

Comment: @PabloAriel It's not really clear what "this" you are talking about, or what you are trying to do, or what platform/toolchain/configuration you are using. I suggest collecting the necessary information then asking a fresh question. It's unlikely to be a bug in anything other than your own code/configuration. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ccda550cce24a6c9

Comment: What is unlikely is my code having more bugs than the MLoCs of codebase making visual studio combined with the android ndk and clang. Also I make heavy use of C++14 and C++17 features so it makes no sense it fails only with stoi. 

You can find the "#if" I've quoted in <basic_string.h> line 2847 or so. 

Also it seems a lot of people had the same problem: [google](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=_GLIBCXX_USE_C99)

I better use a custom implementation written by myself. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @PabloAriel Your code having more bugs than Visual Studio combined with the Android NDK and Clang is _entirely_ likely.

Comment: Weird... when I report bugs to MS they seem to be happy and derive them for fixing instead of telling me my code is wrong. Maybe you should tell them they're wrong. Besides, it's fairly visible how mismanaged are those projects and if you know anything about statistical analysis you could easily note how the bigger the code the more the bugs. Also probably any project that is more than 1mloc is heavily mismanaged, unless it's a program that literally does everything you can imagine.

Comment: @PabloAriel You know best then. Good luck.

Comment: No need for luck... I'd rather bet on knowledge and experience, but thank you anyway.

Comment: @PabloAriel: Great!

Answer (score 10):

[`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) is available only since C++11. In case you don't have C++11 support, here's the C++03 solution based on [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream):

```
std::string test = "45";
std::istringstream is(test);
int myInt;
if (is >> myInt)
    std::cout << myint << std::endl;
```

you just need to `#include <sstream>`

Comment: Also, `std::strtol()`.

Comment: @H2CO3: Yeah, but that's taking C-style `char*` and it's in `<cstdlib>`. But good point :)

Comment: I have C++14 support and I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `stdlib.h`, then other way to make it work is to use `atoi(const char *)`

```
int myint = atoi(test.c_str());
```